# How to pass a datatextfield as a javascript parameter asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

Is there a way I can pass the DeactivatedString text as a javascript parameter? This column has Deactivate and Reactivate as values, and I want to pass them as a parameter to a javascript function named **ShowModal**. I tried like the one below but I encountered "An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request..."

```
                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Tokneneng">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("DeactivatedString")%>' ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" href="#" OnClientClick="return ShowPopup('<%# Eval("DeactivatedString")%>')"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="57px" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: `ShowPopup(this.textContent)`

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Try to use `Bind` instead of `Eval`.